# Are 9000/10000 words enough to be like a real native speaker?

Tags: word-usage, vocabulary

Recently, I've started studying 21.000 word list from the internet. I cannot learn anything from that because when I translate to my native I don't understand the meanings. So that's where my question comes from. If I learn 9000-10000 words will I be able to speak like a native speaker and understand every topic (I will learn the most important ones)?

Comment: One hint: in English, we separate groups of numbers with a comma (**,**) not a period (**.**) so we would write "twenty-one thousand" as **21,000**.  That's the kind of thing that a word list is not going to teach you!

Comment: Speaking or writing a language idiomatically does not come from learning lists of words.

Comment: There is something of an [80/20 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle) in effect, as the frequency with which you use those words is extremely skewed. You use the top few hundred words— mostly determiners, pronouns, prepositions, conjunctions, auxiliary verbs, and the like— vastly more than any others. It doesn't matter if you know *sesquipedalian* but mix up *got*, *gotten*, *have*, *do have*, *did get*, *have got*, and *have gotten*.

Answer (score 5):

How many words you know is pretty much irrelevant (once you get beyond a certain number). You need to understand how to put them together and how to pronounce them in order to "speak like a native speaker". Get that in place, and then you can start expanding your vocabulary.

There is an article on The Economist's website (which I quote in part) that gives some interesting figures:

> Several years ago we mentioned [TestYourVocab.com](http://testyourvocab.com/) here on the blog. Not long ago, the site reached its two millionth test result, and so the researchers have put together some data:
>
> - Most adult native test-takers range from 20,000–35,000 words
> - Average native test-takers of age 8 already know 10,000 words
> - Average native test-takers of age 4 already know 5,000 words
> - Adult native test-takers learn almost 1 new word a day until middle age
> - Adult test-taker vocabulary growth basically stops at middle age
> - The most common vocabulary size for foreign test-takers is 4,500 words
> - Foreign test-takers tend to reach over 10,000 words by living abroad
> - Foreign test-takers learn 2.5 new words a day while living in an English-speaking country

[The Economist](https://www.economist.com/blogs/johnson/2013/05/vocabulary-size)

As you can see, 10,000 words will get you to the level of an average 8-year old. You will need between 20,000-35,000 words to sound like an adult native speaker. However, I am a little dubious about these figures. An adult should be able to make much better use of a 10,000 word vocabulary than any 8-year old, since his thought patterns ought to be more sophisticated.

> "It's not the years, honey. It's the mileage." -- Indiana Jones

Comment: Your link to The Economist throws up a paywall, at least for me  :(

Comment: I don't have a subscription. You're right: they do have a paywall, but they do allow a limited number of accesses (if you register, you are allowed 3 articles per week). Actually, I've just realised that I haven't quoted the entire article. I'm not sure if the site rules allow it, anyway.

Comment: That's a lot. How can a foreign speaker learn these 35.000 words? You are lucky as you are a native speaker :(

Comment: @NickBoss No two native English speakers will know the same 35,000 words (and not even the same 20,000 words). Treat these figures with a "grain of salt" (don't take them too seriously). Learn the words in your key vocabulary (whatever that is), and master grammar and pronunciation as well as you can. Don't fret about pronunciation. Most English speakers are used to foreigners struggling with the language, and will be patient with you.

Comment: @Mick What did you mean by "test-taskers"?

Comment: @NickBoss "Test-taker" -- someone who takes a test.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Mick that sounding like a native speaker has very little to do with the number of words you know.  Just because you can give me the book definitions of (for example) "dirty", "grimy", and "squalid" doesn't mean you can use each in the correct context.

Personally, I think fluency is more about phrases than words, and more about idiom than vocabulary.  For example, do you know what I mean when I say

> My soda has **gone flat**

How about:

> She **flatly** refused my proposal

or

> She has a nice singing voice, but she keeps **going flat**.

Some English words have as many as a dozen different meanings, depending on context.  A fluent speaker would know most or all of them, or at least be able to take a good guess.

Comment: Andrew, I'll take a wild guess as to what these phrases mean. The first means _run_ _out_; the second _definately_; the third probably means she cannot sustain a high tone of voice throughout. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: @Sara  1.  the soda has lost its carbonation -- that is, there are no more bubbles, 2. she refused my proposal without listening to any counter-argument, 3.  the singer's notes are slightly below perfect pitch (*flat* here is actually more a musical term than an idiom).  But I wasn't really trying to test you, I just wanted to give an example where a simple word like "flat" can have many different meanings, in different contexts.  I'm sure it's similar with your own native language.

Comment: When I was learning Japanese I spent a lot of time listening to native speakers and copying their patterns.  While this got me in trouble in some ways, it did help me *sound* more fluent because I would use natural-sounding, complete sentences.

Comment: Andrew, Thanks a lot. You're a wonderful teacher. I'm going to note down your definitions once I get home. And yes, Arabic is pretty much the same as English in that both have rich and diverse meanings for their words

Comment: I've been learning English for so long that my academic and formal vocabulary is analogous to a native speaker's. I'm still struggling, however, with informal and slang language because these require a lot of practise, which I don't have access to. To make up for the fact that language immersion is missing I've been adopting an approach that has proved effective. I've downloaded and watched every single episode of the TV show _Friends_ 5 times over a period of 5 years. I've learned the script by heart. Breaking Bad is next.

Comment: @Sara my ex-wife learned her English the same way, by watching *Friends* and *Seinfeld*.  Both are a little dated now, but still pretty funny.  I haven't watched all of *Breaking Bad* but be aware some of the characters have a strong accent and use a lot of slang expressions associated with criminals (which you shouldn't use unless you want to sound like a drug dealer ;)

Comment: then I probably shouldn't watch it. I was thinking of _the_ _Simpsons_ as an alternative. What do you recommend?

Comment: @Sara I've heard *Breaking Bad* is extremely good, and most of the characters talk in standard American English.  You should be able to figure out which ones are using dialect, so it should be educational.

Comment: @Sara do watch Breaking Bad, I learnt so many Americanisms, it was a delight. And the Shakespearian protagonist, Walter White, always speaks grammatically correct  English. It's very clear because WW's pronunciation is never slurred; added bonus, he never once gets his "whos" or "whoms" mixed up :)

Comment: @Sara Try *The Wire* if you want Baltimore AmE. There's 60 hours of it. It's excellent TV, btw.

Comment: @Mick  Great show, but that'll be fun time learning what half the characters are saying  :)

Answer (score 2):

Of course not! There are about 180,000 fundamental words in English (more than 3 million definitions, phrases, Idioms), and learning all of them is definitely futile, because it will take 30 years to memorize and put them in use, therefore you need to work on the 20,000 to 40,000 words almost all native speakers know; I have never agreed with the sentence: "Proficient speakers of English know 15,000 words or so.", it has to be somewhere around 200,000 , because English is the largest language in the world and Bear in mind that 90 percent of its words have more than two meanings (It depends on the dialect you aim at). Two years ago, when I was fifteen (I was so eager to learn words since childhood), I found a new website that really developed my vocabulary, it was called ***Wordhippo***, with the help of that website I have reached a good point in vocabulary so far, but I'm still not able to understand English well. -Why? - The reason is that I have never been to any English speaking country and the most accurate answer is that I still have more important business to  do and that's why I forget words easily. The point is that you can't be as good as you want at English until you are **Submerged** or (better to say) **Absorbed** in it. Don't worry about the number of words, just focus on **Usage Frequency** and **Common Phrases** if you don't want to take your time. In the end, I'd recommend you to use the website I mentioned.
Good Luck!!!